# Pausing Bluetooth Notifications in Capacitor Community Plugin

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps, capacitor, plugin.bluetoothle

I'm working on a project using the capacitor-community/bluetooth-le plugin to communicate with a Bluetooth device. I've encountered an issue where I need to pause listening to incoming Bluetooth notifications while executing a sub-routine triggered by a previous notification.

In my connect() function, I start listening to Bluetooth notifications using BleClient.startNotifications(). However, I've noticed that in certain scenarios, I need to temporarily block the plugin from listening to notifications while I perform a specific task in the openGate() function.

Here's a simplified version of the relevant code:

```
async connect() {
  // ...
  await BleClient.startNotifications(
    this.connectedDeviceId,
    READ_SERVICE,
    READ_CHARACTERISTIC,
    (value) => {
      if (!shouldListenForNotifications) return;
      let keypadNotification: number = dataViewToNumbers(value)[0];
      this.openGate(keypadNotification);
    }
  );
}

async openGate(keypadNotification: number) {
  if (keypadNotification === 1) {
    shouldListenForNotifications = false;
    setTimeout(async () => {
      // Perform sub-routine
      shouldListenForNotifications = true;
    }, 0);
  }
  // ... (similar logic for other cases)
}
```

Is there a recommended approach to temporarily pause the Bluetooth notifications while executing the sub-routine? I want to ensure that I don't miss any notifications during the pause and that the communication remains reliable.

Any guidance, best practices, or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!